# Elasticsearch: Alias pointing to an alias

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES aliases for decoupling index names with the application using ES

```
ALIAS NAME      INDEX NAME

user_index    - user
project_index - project
org_index     - org
```

Now I need another alias pointing to all the three aliases, to maintain one single point of search (for supporting existing APIs)

Can I have another alias pointing to all the three aliases here? Something like.

```
main_index __ user_index
           \__ project_index 
            \__ org_index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this capability does not yet exist in Elasticsearch.

There is an outstanding issue requesting this capability. Please see [Elasticsearch Issue #3138](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3138) for more details related to the requested functionality. Please note that this particular issue has been open for over a year, but there has not been any comment from anyone on the Elasticsearch development team. Therefore, I am not sure how long it will be until this capability is implemented within Elasticsearch.

Comment: It is now closed without resolution. :(

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can have as many aliases as you want on your index.
So, you can set an other alias "main_index" directly on your three index. 
Wouldn't that be enough to suit your needs?